# prove :nth root of the Product of arithmetic sequence is bigger than the sqrt of the first and last numbers

Tags: calculus, products, arithmetic-progressions

let $ \{a_n\} $ be an arithmetic sequence of positive numbers.

prove that for all $ n\ge2 $:

$ \frac{a_{1}+a_{n}}{2}\ge\sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\dots a_{n}}\ge\sqrt{a_{1}a_{n}} $

I managed to solve the left part of the inequality by using the sum of the arithmetic sequence and the EM-GM inequality.

I'm having issues with the right side, tried using ln on everything and induction but the algebra was too tough. Also tried comparing with the harmonic mean
Any other methods to solve this with calculus 1 tools(haven't learned about $ \Gamma $ function yet) ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n = a + (n-1)d$.

Then for $0 < m < n-1$ we have:

$$a_{1 + m}a_{n-m} = (a_1 + md)(a_n -md) \\= a_1a_n+(a_n-a_1)md-(md)^2 =a_1a_n +md((n-1-m)d)\ge a_1a_n$$

Now consider $(\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\dots a_n})^2 = \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\dots a_n}\sqrt[n]{a_na_{n-1}\dots a_1} = \sqrt[n]{(a_1a_n)(a_2a_{n-1})\dots(a_na_1)}$.

By our result above, that expression cannot be less than $\sqrt[n]{(a_1a_n)^n} = a_1a_n$.

Therefore $\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\dots a_n} \ge \sqrt{a_1a_n}$.

Comment: If $a_1=1$ and $a_n=n$ we can show that:

$$\sqrt[n]{1\times2\times3\times4\cdot\cdot\cdot\times n}\geq\sqrt n$$. would you like to see the proof as the answer to your question?

Comment: That's actually the 2nd part of the question but if I prove the first part this is trivial.  
I think I can solve for $ d=1 $, its the general $ d>0 $ that is tough.  
Still trying to figure out a way to use the hint above, so far all i've only infered that for every $ n>m \Rightarrow a_n >md $

Comment: @DannyBlozrov: I messed up the sign of the inequality. I fixed that and have now expanded my hint into a full answer.

Comment: Beautiful solution.  
What gave you the intuition to square it? I took both sides of the equation and upped them by a power of $ 2n $ and got something similar when trying induction but it became too complicated.

Comment: There were two: 1. For two pairs of numbers with the same mean, the pair further away would have the smaller product - that led to the hint. 2. For the product itself, I was trying to replicate Gauss' Proof for $1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + n = n(n+1)/2$, by pairing $a_{1+m}$ with $a_{n-m}$.